# Action Needed | OAuth Google Cloud platform | multiple unique domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I am carrying out the OAuth verification in Google Cloud Platform, I received an email that said:

"Thanks for your patience while we reviewed your project.

Your project pc-api-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XX has multiple unique domains in the redirect URI and origin URLs, many of which have unrelated applications. This is in direct violation of the Google API Services: User Data Policy, which requires that projects accurately represent their identity and intent to Google and to our users when they request access to Google user data.

Please follow the instructions on the Google API Console to:

Create new projects
Migrate your redirect URIs with distinct brands to different projects, and/or
Ensure that these projects accurately represent their true identity to Google users
You can find more information in the OAuth Application Verification FAQ.  To make sure we don't miss your messages, respond directly to this email to continue with the verification process."

I have a web server, which checks the validity (domain-1.com) in-app purchases, and I also have a site with a different domain containing: privacy-policy and terms-of-service (domain-2.com).

My settings are as follows:

OAuth consent screen:

- Home page application: https://www.domain-2.com/
- Privacy Policy: https://www.domain-2.com/privacy-policy/
- Terms of Service: https://www.domain-2.com/terms-of-service/

Authorized domains:

- domain-2.com
- domain-1.com

ID client OAuth 2.0 -> Authorized Redirect URIs:

- https://game.domain-1.com:8443

I have a working service account.
I have successfully verified all 2 domains.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

I had 2 Google Cloud Platform projects for the same application.

I deleted a Google Cloud Platform.
I implemented all the configurations of the deleted project in the other project, and it worked!